# How to display a customized code in C# & DevExexpress TextEditor with mask

Tags: c#

I am trying to display a code like ABC/DEF/00012 or ABC/EDF/01234 or ABC/DEF/00009

I use RegEx mask \w{3}/\w{3}/?????

The question mark is hard part that I could not figure it out.

Basically, I try to display the code with characters and numbers. I want to automatically add leading zeros on the number.

Byron

Comment: Is there anyone who could help me with?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, this is about C#, the question marked as duplicate is solving it with unix shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're trying to match 5 digits at the end:

\w{3}/\w{3}/\d{5}

Comment: When I try to do this -- textEdit1.Text = "LPO/ADL/44" -- with w{3}/\w{3}/\d{5} 

It gives me LPO/ADL/44

Comment: I want to display LPO/ADL/00044